# I want to start my app from the home activity every time. it is not working

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my code for my exit button. But it is starting from the last activity i opened.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SplashActivity.class); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

And it is the code of the activity from which I want to start  everytime

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it for your exit button.

```
        Second_activity.this.finish();
        Intent intentMain = new Intent(Second_activity.this ,  com.project.test.MainActivity.class);
        Second_activity.this.startActivity(intentMain);
```